# User context for @Startup EJB on websphere

Tags: ejb, websphere, websphere-8

Where do I set the user context Websphere uses when it calls a @Startup EJB?

I have a Java EE application with a startup EJB, and I know that it sets a user when calling the EJB, since the call fails due to missing roles. However, I couldn't find where to set the user.

Comment: Can you show the stack trace of the failure?  The invocation of the `@PostConstruct` of a `@Startup` EJB should not require any authorization.  However, if the `@PostConstruct` makes another call that does require authorization, that would fail; in that case, you would either need to programmatically set the context (using `WSLogin` or equivalent) or use `@RunAs` for the EJB and configure a run-as user (note: this will affect all calls the EJB makes, not just those from `@PostConstruct`).

Comment: This question is not about the failure (I know about `@RunAs`, though it doesn't work as I expected, but that is another question). This question is about the user context. I know there is one, since WAS gives the user name in the Exception. I just can't figure out where to set it. I know that I may not need to set it, if `@RunAs` works as advertised, but I still want to know :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EJB spec states that session bean `@PostConstruct` methods are called in an unspecified security context, and WebSphere does not document a specific security context or allow it to be configured.  In practice, singleton session bean `@PostConstruct` will typically be called with an unauthorized user as the security context.  If setting a specific security context is important, then you could open a [WebSphere RFE](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/?BRAND_ID=181), but I would recommend finding another solution to avoid a vendor-specific solution.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I posted a question about my problems to get `@RunAs` to work here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33118280/cant-get-runas-to-work-in-an-ejb ,