# @Schedule and @RunAs in Glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb

I'm running GlassFish Server 4.1 and I want to call a method periodically so I am using @Schedule, the method requires a role so I added @RunAs to the class. But no matter how I try I can not get this to work.

```
@Singleton
@Startup
@RunAs("Tool")
public class Test {
    @Resource 
    private SessionContext ctx;

    @Schedule(minute = "*/1", hour = "*")
    public void checkExpiringAgreements() {
        System.out.println("Has role Tool: " + ctx.isCallerInRole("Tool"));
    }
}
```

This runs every minute, but it prints:

```
Info:   Has role Tool: false
```

If I had any hair I'd be tearing it out right now. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: I wonder if Glassfish requires additional configuration is required for the Tool role to specify which specific identity should be used.  I know WebSphere Application Server does: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33118280/cant-get-runas-to-work-in-an-ejb.  Otherwise, I can only say your use of the annotations looks correct, so it should be possible to make it work.

Comment: Try declaring your role in class by `@DeclareRoles({"Tool"})`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the security realm and make sure the principal has the role you are setting in the @RunAs:

1) From **@RunAs javadoc**: *"The role must map to the user / group information in the containers security realm"*.

2) From **EJB 3.2 spec.:** *"Establishing a run-as identity for an enterprise bean does not affect the identities of its callers, which are the identities tested for permission to access the methods of the enterprise bean."*

***Note***: because the Bean Developer / Application Assembler don't usually know about the security configuration details, they can set a "logical" role so that the Deployer will later know how to set it in the groups-roles-users mapping.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is, like me, been searching for this issue: when use use RunAs("Tool") then that role is set for outgoing calls.

So you should create a different EJB that you call and inside that EJB you will have the tool role.